# Does the argument of Julia function Task(func) have to be a function?

Tags: function, julia

While trying to learn parallel programming with julia, I came across the function `Task(func)` which, according to julia documentation, creates a callable task that executes the function `func` and can be run later. However, it seems that `func` doesn't have to be a function; any set of statements will do. For example:

```
t = Task(begin; sleep(5); println("done"); end)
schedule(t)
```

which gives the following result upon execution with julia 1.6.2

```
done
```

This is confusing. Do the set of statements `begin; sleep(5); println("done"); end` constitute a function (anonymous). If so, how? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the result of running of the code you have shown:

```
julia> t = Task(begin; sleep(5); println("done"); end)
done
Task (runnable) @0x000000001ad02400

julia> schedule(t)
Task (failed) @0x000000001ad02400
MethodError: objects of type Nothing are not callable
```

And this is expected, the code block:

```
begin; sleep(5); println("done"); end
```

yields `nothing` as its value (as this is what `println` returns), and then `nothing` is passed as an argument to `Task`. Then when you try to schedule the task it errors.

Note that the code block:

```
begin; sleep(5); println("done"); end
```

gets evaluated before its value is passed to `Task` constructor.

Comment: Interesting. I was actually running the code from a script and didn't get the error message. Thank you!